# SKScene didChangeSize: called multiple times

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Why is it called twice every time I change the orientation?
Is it a bug or?

It's even being called when I override `setSize` with nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem with Swift UI SpriteView. I don't change size programmatically anywhere, the scene is empty, but `didChangeSize` is called 3 times when UI is loaded and twice per each device rotation. It also reports the same repeated sizes. Ew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is a correct behavior.

```
- (void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize
```

is called whenever the scene’s size changes. This obviously happens when you rotate the device. It can also be that you are calling some code after the rotation happens that triggers size change and that's why you see `didChangeSize` being called twice.

Comment: I may have overlooked a semantic bug in my own code. However I ended up not using it.

Comment: I think the correct behavior would be calling this method once per size change. It's definitely a dirty implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to override the setter. In Objective-C you just override `-setSize:` and don't forget to call `super`. In Swift you override the `size` variable and implement `didSet`:

```
override var size: CGSize {
    didSet {
        print("didSetSize:", size)
    }
}
```

In my case (Swift UI SpriteView) `didChangeSize` was called twice per change, while didSet - only once. I had console logs like:

```
didChangeSize old: (810.0, 1080.0) new: (1080.0, 810.0)
didSetSize: (1080.0, 810.0)
didChangeSize old: (810.0, 1080.0) new: (1080.0, 810.0)
```